# Comparison of Transaction Speeds vs. Other Platforms

Tags: transactions, speed

Does anyone have a comparison of technologies and transaction speeds/costs for XLM vs. Ripple vs. SWIFT vs. Conventional Mediums.

It would be great to create an infographic or comparison table based on this information to easily share it and inform others.

Some data points that would be useful:

- Technology Used
- Open Sourced?
- Supply
- Speed (Per Transaction and Transactions/Second for the network)
- Cost (Per Transaction)

Comment: This question is very broad and requires a lot of work on the responder's end. I suggest that you edit the question to be less broad or move this to the subreddit and start a discussion about gathering the requested information there.

Answer (score -1):

Not a comparison, but an infographic for Stellar: [image: /r/Stellar Infographic]